# Why do we use the word "unborn" instead of "nonborn"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Wouldn't "un-" imply something that occurred and then was reversed? Like undo, untie, unravel? If a child is in utero, shouldn't we call it "nonborn"? When did "unborn" become popular?

Comment: Looking in the OED, I find "unborn" as early as 897, but "nonborn" isn't a word.  Ngram shows "nonborn" taking off around 1960.  I guess one side or the other of the abortion debate thought "unborn" had the wrong connotatins for their argument.

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't "un-" imply something that occurred and then was reversed? Like undo, untie, unravel?

When attached to an adjective, *un-* means "not": "unhappy", "unclear", "untrue". One of the many ways that participles resemble adjectives in English is that they can take this prefix: "unknown", "unbroken", "unopened".

With "unborn", I think you're trying to interpret it as the past participle of *"unbear", hence using the "reverse" meaning of *un-*; but in fact it's "un-" + "born", and just means "not (yet) born".

Some forms are ambiguous — "undone" can mean either "reversed" (past participle of "undo") or "not (yet) done" (opposite of "done") — but I think "unborn" really has only the one meaning.

Comment: It's really difficult to undo a birth.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "Nicodemus saith unto [Jesus], How can a man be born when he is old? can he enter the second time into his mother's womb, and be born?" John 3:4